# about the key ”defer”and “select” in Go

Tags: go

```
func TestContext(t *testing.T){
    message:=make(chan int,10)
    //producer
    for i:=0;i<10;i++{
        message<-i
    }
    
    //consumer
    ctx,cancel:=context.WithTimeout(context.Background(),time.Second*5)

    go func(ctx context.Context) {
            ticker := time.NewTicker(1 * time.Second)
            for _ = range ticker.C { 
                select {
                case <-ctx.Done():
                    fmt.Println("child process interrupt...")
                    return
                default:
                    fmt.Printf("send message: %d\n", <-message)
                }
            }
        }(ctx)
    
    defer close(message)
    defer cancel()
    select{
        case <-ctx.Done():
            //time.Sleep(1*time.Second)
            fmt.Println("main process exit!")
    }

}
```

Q1: when is the “defer cancel” executed? after select ?

Q2: In Q1,if "defer cancel" is executed after select , will the ctx.Done() return nil? and will the select be blocked?

Comment: "defer cancel" is executed at the line you write it but "cancel" is executed when the function returns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All deferred function calls will run after the function body runs, but before the function returns, so yes, defer cancel will execute after `select`.

Select will block until the context times out. When the context times out, the `<-ctx.Done()` case will be enabled, so select can continue after the context timeout.